# NaN size of a grid

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a WPF User control, let's name it MyControl, which has a Grid that contains some Drawing Visuals and the same Grid it is contained inside another grid. The width and the height of MyControl are binded to the Width and Height properties of the UserControl.And the UserControl contains the grid inside which the Drawing Visual is contained.

Then I have another WPF User control which creates N of MyControl and places them inside a Dock Panel.

The issue that I'm facing is that whenever I access any of MyControl's Width and Height properties they are actually NaN.

Following is my DockPanel declaration :

```
<DockPanel x:Name="layout" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch">
    </DockPanel>
```

The other controls are initialized at runtime. What could be a reason for this to happen. Also there's something else that's odd - MyControl seems to behave properly whenever it is used as a single control but whenever I try to use the control which contains N of them, the events seem to mess up.

Could it be because the Binding hasn't yet taken place? Infact when does the Binding actually take place so I can be certain that they are Binded?

```
    Container = new Container(Data);
    Container.SetBinding(Grid.WidthProperty, new Binding("Width") { Source = this });
    Container.SetBinding(Grid.HeightProperty, new Binding("Height") { Source = this });
    grid.Children.Add(Container);
    myControl.AddChild(grid);
```

Here's how I bind the inner grid to the size of the UserControl.

I solved my problem by binding the Container's class Grid to the Actual width property of the UserControl like this :

```
       Container.SetBinding(Grid.WidthProperty, new Binding("ActualWidth") { Source = this });
        Container.SetBinding(Grid.HeightProperty, new Binding("ActualHeight") { Source = this });
```

Like so.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, you should use `ActualWidth` and `ActualHeight` properties to get the size of a control.

Second, you need to let WPF do it's layouting pass to have Actual sizes set. This should usually be done in Loaded event or somewhere other.

Lastly, you should not read and write sizes yourself, you should set up the layouting so WPF does the sizing itself.

Comment: So I'am assuming that I can use the ActualWidth and ActualHeight after the Grid has been instantiated and Binded right?

Comment: @Chris No. You need to let application "run" for second so WPF does it's layouting. OnLoaded event for example happens after that. I can't right now name any other events that could be used for similar thing.

Answer (score 1):

Use the ActualWidth and ActualHeight properties if you want to know the actual current size.

The Width and Height properties return NaN because that means that the Width and Height are not specified or explicitly set and therefore WPF can determine the (needed) size automatically.

Comment: The problem is that whenever I get the size of the Container it is still NaN, but if I move up the visual tree and find the first that has non zero it tells me that the only controls which has a width and height is the one that contains the multiple controls. The individual controls seem not to have any actual size, they are equal to 0.0.

Comment: NaN means that the width and height properties are set to Auto

Answer (score 0):

NaN is to mean "not set". FrameworkElement is the base class for many Controls in WPF and if you do not explicitly set the Height and Width properties then in the class constructor will be a default value of NaN.

In this case try get the ActualWidth, instead of Width and ActualHeight instead of Height: